# At what point in time is this "sendcmpct" message sent

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoin-core-development

In Bitcoin Core, when setting a node to either high-bandwidth mode or low-bandwidth mode, a "sendcmpct" message is sent. At what point in time is this "sendcmpct" message sent? Is it sent every time a block is received? I would also like information about the implementation details.